# Error when running :PlugInstall

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I want to use vim-plug for managing plugins, but when I run ":PlugInstall" this error is thrown:
[Vim error after :PlugInstall in cmder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5o9wd.png)

I only have this in the vimrc file:

```
call plug#begin()
Plug 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
call plug#end()

set ruler
set number

set laststatus=2
```

I am using Windows 10 x64, cmder as terminal and vim 7.4.827.

Comment: You need `git` install and in your PATH

Comment: Well, it is installed and in my path, I use quite often from the command line... Is there any extra steps I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the citation of the plugin's wiki post [Windows System Error E484](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug/wiki/faq#windows-system-error-e484):

> There are two possible causes we've encountered.
>
> 1. Bad escaping. On Windows, if you use '<', '>' or '|' in the file path, vim-plug is known to fail. Any other chars should be fine.
> 2. System changes due to AutoRun commands executed on cmd.exe startup. See
>      [docs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779439%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).
>
> To see if your system suffers this second problem, run these reg
>   queries. If either one returns a path to a bat file, you should
>   carefully read it. You may have to edit/disable it to get vim-plug
>   working.
>
> ```
> REG QUERY "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v AutoRun
> REG QUERY "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v AutoRun
> ```

PS: The [issues 229](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug/issues/229) might be interesting to read.

PPS: Also if you have only mentioned lines in your _vimrc then you are probably missing `set nocompatible`.

Comment: Thank you for your help ryuichiro, I don't have of the special characters in the file path. When running the commands, I have this error:
http://oi65.tinypic.com/fd810i.jpg

Comment: O.k.. Have you try to create the directory (for example, C:\tmp, with read and write permission), and `let $TMP="c:/tmp"`. Also what is your output of `set shell?`, and `set shellslash?` ?

Comment: Thank you for your help, doing a `set shell?` showed me that it was pointing to a non-existing file, I changed that to the sh.exe in `cmder\vendor\git-for-windows\bin` the errors disappeared, but I still can't use :PlugInstall because when "installing", the folder path that appears doesn't have any backslash "\". but I guess I should post that in another shouldn't I?

Comment: You can also try to point to default cmd by `set shell=cmd`, and `set shellcmdflag=/c`. Or you can try to `set noshelltemp` instead. If it doesn't help, then I would recommend you to visit the issue trackers of `vim-plug` and `cmder`, and try to ask there.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason your temp folder seems to be not writeable. It's located at `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp`. Check if the folder has the read-only attribute in its settings and uncheck it if possible.

Comment: Thank your for your answer, I tried that, I also tried launching cmder as administrator and tried launching gvim as admin as well, but to no avail...